# Adding a new XML node to a last one of the same sort

Tags: c#, xml

I have an Excel table saved as a XML file, so there are some rows there. All I want is to add a new row to the last one using C#.

Structure:

```
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook>
  <DocumentProperties>
    ...
  </DocumentProperties>
  <OfficeDocumentSettings>
    ...
  </OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <ExcelWorkbook>
    ...
  </ExcelWorkbook>
  <Styles>
    ...
  </Styles>
  <Worksheet ss:Name="TDSheet">
    <Table>
      <Column>
        ...
      </Column>
        ...
      <Column>
        ...
      </Column>
      <Row>
        ...
      </Row>
      <!-- HIER SHOULD APPEAR MY NEW ROW -->
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

I use XmlDocument class.

Comment: Any reason *why* you're using `XmlElement` rather than LINQ to XML? I would definitely use the latter wherever you can... it's a significantly cleaner API.

Comment: I have already written a procedure that reads an XML document using XmlElement, that's the only reason. I don't want to mix the code.

Comment: Well how hard would it be to convert that to use `XElement`? If it's *really* just reading a document, it should be trivial...

Comment: If you show me the way it functions with LINQ to XML, then I'll delete the last line of my original message : )

Comment: The way what functions? You mean how I'd answer *this* question using LINQ to XML? Sure, I can do that - but first, are there ever multiple `Worksheet` elements or multiple `Table` elements? Because basically you only need to find the `Table` element...

Comment: There is only one Worksheet element and only one Table element there.

Comment: In that case, the answer I've given should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to find the relevant `Table` element, then append a new `Row` element to that. For example, using LINQ to XML, assuming there *is* only one `Table` element:

```
var doc = ...; // XDocument.Load or whatever
var table = doc.Descendants("Table").First();
table.Add(new XElement("Row", ...));
```

If there can be more than one `Table` element, you need to work out how to find the right one - which we can't tell at the moment from your question.

Comment: What if I have XmlDocument instead of XDocument? Then there's no Descendants list there.

Comment: @relapse: Yes, `XDocument` is easier to use than `XmlDocument`, which is why I recommended using it in the comments. We discussed it in the comments in the question, and you said: "If you show me the way it functions with LINQ to XML, then I'll delete the last line of my original message" - hence this answer. This can certainly be done using `XmlDocument`, but I'd *very strongly* recommend using LINQ to XML instead. It's a *miles* better API.

Comment: I discovered a new problem in the XML code, in browsers it's represented in a different way as it actually is. The problem is that some elements are supplied with a prefix - in my case it's ss:    But I can't form a list beginning with a "ss:Table" element and consequently I can't add a new Element "ss:Row".

Comment: @relapse: Then you need to use a namespace. That's very easy to do in LINQ to XML, but I didn't do it in my answer as the XML you showed didn't have any namespaces for the element names...